# Duplication in Dockerfiles

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a Django Web-Application that uses celery in the background for periodic tasks.

Right now I have three docker images

- one for the django application
- one for celery workers
- one for the celery scheduler

whose `Dockerfile`s all look like this:

```
FROM alpine:3.7

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
COPY Pipfile Pipfile.lock ./

RUN apk update && \
 apk add python3 postgresql-libs jpeg-dev git && \
 apk add --virtual .build-deps gcc python3-dev musl-dev postgresql-dev zlib-dev && \
 pip3 install --no-cache-dir pipenv && \
 pipenv install --system && \
 apk --purge del .build-deps

COPY . ./

# Run the image as a non-root user
RUN adduser -D noroot
USER noroot

EXPOSE $PORT

CMD <Different CMD for all three containers>
```

So they are all exactly the same except the last line.

Would it make sense here to create some kind of base image that contains everything except CMD. And all three images use that as base and add only their respective CMD?

Or won't that give me any advantages, because everything is cached anyway?

Is a seperation like you see above reasonable?

Two small bonus questions:

- Sometimes the `apk update ..` layer is cached by docker. How does docker know that there are no updates here?
- I often read that I should decrease layers as far a possible to reduce image size. But isn't that against the caching idea and will result in longer builds?

Comment: this would be a good place to use [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) with a single image, and override CMD for each service

Comment: as for when `apk update` is cached, docker doesn't know. Your `apk update` and installation will only run if you change the set of packages being installed (which invalidates the cache for that line) or you edit your `Pipfile` or `Pipfile.lock` (which invalidates the cached `COPY` command above it and all subsequent steps)

Comment: @avigil reasonable suggestion, but I also want to deploy my application to heroku. And it does not use docker-compose afaik.

Answer (score 3):

I will suggest to use one Dockerfile and just update your CMD during runtime. Litle bit modification will work for both local and Heroku as well.

As far Heroku is concern they provide environment variable to start container with the environment variable.
[heroku set-up-your-local-environment-variables](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-local#set-up-your-local-environment-variables)

```
    FROM alpine:3.7

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV APPLICATION_TO_RUN=default_application

RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
COPY Pipfile Pipfile.lock ./

RUN apk update && \
 apk add python3 postgresql-libs jpeg-dev git && \
 apk add --virtual .build-deps gcc python3-dev musl-dev postgresql-dev zlib-dev && \
 pip3 install --no-cache-dir pipenv && \
 pipenv install --system && \
 apk --purge del .build-deps

COPY . ./

# Run the image as a non-root user
RUN adduser -D noroot
USER noroot

EXPOSE $PORT

CMD $APPLICATION_TO_RUN
```

So When run you container pass your application name to run command.

```
docker run -it --name test -e APPLICATION_TO_RUN="celery beat" --rm test
```

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend looking at [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) to simplify management of multiple containers.

Use a single Dockerfile like the one you posted above, then create a `docker-compose.yml` that might look something like this:

```
version: '3'
services:
  # a django service serving an application on port 80
  django:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver
    ports:
      - 8000:80
  # the celery worker
  worker:
    build: .
    command: celery worker
  # the celery scheduler
  scheduler:
    build: .
    command: celery beat
```

Of course, modify the commands here to be whatever you are using for your currently separate Dockerfiles.

When you want to rebuild the image, `docker-compose build` will rebuild your container image from your Dockerfile for the first service, then reuse the built image for the other services (because they already exist in the cache). `docker-compose up` will spin up 3 instances of your container image, but overriding the run command each time.

If you want to get more sophisticated, there are [plenty of resources](https://blog.syncano.io/configuring-running-django-celery-docker-containers-pt-1/) out there for the very common combination of django and celery.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I didn't knew about the `command` key in docker-compose. I actually use docker-compose already for local development. 

But I also deploy my application to Heroku and afaik can't it handle docker-compose. So I think I'm stuck with using three Dockerfiles

Answer (score 1):

Late, but for those still looking for a solution, standard multi-stage Docker builds can let you specify the uncommon logic for each scenario in a stage, and specify at build time which stage you'd like to build.

For a very simple example, with the Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu as build
# Your common logic here

FROM build as one
CMD ["/bin/bash", "-c", "echo foo"]

FROM build as two
CMD ["/bin/bash", "-c", "echo bar"]
```

you can do `docker build --target one .` to produce an image that prints the output "foo", and `docker build --target two .` to produce an image that prints the output "bar."

In scenarios where the difference between the final stages is small - e.g., just a different entrypoint - it's a convenient approach.